# Задать фон на всю ширину и высоту экрана

Tags: html, css

Я новичок в верстке хотел узнать, т.к. не какой информации практически не нашел либо не правильно задавал вопрос.Как сделать в таком порядке 3 любых цвета на полный экран для любого разрешения мониторов.Я пришел к такому выводу, что нужно создавать `div`, где указывать `width` и `height` для цвета, но это же не подойдет к разрешению других мониторов[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.block_1,
.block_2,
.block_3 {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.block_1 {
  background-color: red;
}
.block_2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.block_3 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="block_1 block_height"></div>
<div class="block_2 block_height"></div>
<div class="block_3 block_height"></div>
```

Comment: А возможно как то реализовать без `js` ?

Comment: А возможно реализовать как то так, псевдокод такой 

`body{ background-color: green 100%, yellow 100%}` таким образом чтобы у нас появилось 2 цвета с возможностью прокрутки вниз и они занимали всё разрешение экрана? Ну т.е. сначала на всю ширину и высоту экрана у нас был бы зеленый, потом когда крутишь вниз желтый

Comment: Простите, чуть не успел до вашего ответа

Comment: Да, это то что нужно, спасибо вам!